# expresso store orders between date range

Tags: expresso-store, devdemon, expresso

Is it possible to filter Expresso Store 2 orders between two dates in a template? EG the customer wants to see all their orders between 2013 and 2014.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this pretty simply with this:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT order_hash FROM exp_store_orders WHERE order_completed_date > 1356998400 AND order_completed_date < 1420070400"}
{exp:store:orders order_hash="{order_hash}"}
Order #{order_id}
{/exp:store:orders}
{/exp:query}
```

Brad

Comment: Thanks so much for this was a great (and simple) solution